# SyncFiles - NullReferenceException [P4API]

Tags: c#, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I'm starting to build a custom GUI for Perforce, I could list my DepotFiles, but when I try to do something with my client, I'm getting `NullReferenceException`.

I couldn't find much about SyncFiles method, and Perforce's API documentation doesn't help at all.

Here goes what i have:

```
try
{
    Repository rep = con.Repositorio;
    Client Workspace;
    FileSpec files;
    IList<FileSpec> FilesFound;
    List<FileSpec> arquivos;
    arquivos = new List<FileSpec>();

    Workspace = rep.GetClient("Perforce_wp");
    files = new FileSpec(new ClientPath("//..."), VersionSpec.Head);
    arquivos.Add(files);
    FilesFound = Workspace.SyncFiles(arquivos, null);


     MessageBox.Show(FilesFound.Count.ToString(), "Title");
}
catch (P4Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error");
}
```

But my FilesFound list is returning null, probably there's something wrong, but I can't figure out what.
I've checked and my Client is returning correctly, the connection is successful etc.

Can someone more experienced with the API points me what could possibly be wrong?

---

Some detailed information about the exception raised when calling `SyncFiles` method in r13.1 version of p4api.net:

```
P4APIException: Client.SyncFiles: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Perforce.P4.Client.runFileListCmd(String cmdName, Options options, String commandData, FileSpec[] files) in c:\tmp\21439306\src\P4.NET\r13.1\p4api.net\p4api.net\Client.cs:line 815
at Perforce.P4.Client.SyncFiles(Options options, FileSpec[] files) in c:\tmp\21439306\src\P4.NET\r13.1\p4api.net\p4api.net\Client.cs:line 3165
```

Comment: Which line of your code is the NullReferenceException occurring at?

Comment: Exaclty the same line where syncfiles is being called.    
FilesFound = Workspace.SyncFiles(arquivos, null);

Comment: Can you tell if the variable named "Workspace" is null at that point? Perhaps "rep.GetClient(Perforce_wp)" is returning null? Do you have a workspace named "Perforce_wp" on this server?

Comment: I have similar problem using r13.1 version of p4api.net. ``P4APIException: Client.SyncFiles: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Perforce.P4.Client.runFileListCmd(String cmdName, Options options, String commandData, FileSpec[] files) in c:\tmp\21439306\src\P4.NET\r13.1\p4api.net\p4api.net\Client.cs:line 815
   at Perforce.P4.Client.SyncFiles(Options options, FileSpec[] files) in c:\tmp\21439306\src\P4.NET\r13.1\p4api.net\p4api.net\Client.cs:line 3165``

Comment: I don't know if the are uvailable anywhere sources of p4api.net in that specific version but I found *some* sources here: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4api-net/files/main/p4api.net/Client.cs#commits Unfortunately they are not very helpful.